# Problem while decrypting a file with AES, gives Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode

Tags: python, error-handling, cryptography, aes

Hi I'm programming a basic project about Shamir Secret Sharing but I having a problem while decrypting a file.
I'm using AES to encrypt and decrypt

My code to encrypt:

```
   def encrypt_text(self, text):
    pad_text = pad(text, AES.block_size)
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    password = self.alphanumric_pass(self.key)
    cipher = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(pad_text)
    
def encrypt_file(self):
    try:
        
        with open(self.file, 'rb') as f:
            orig_file = f.read()
            
        enc_text = self.encrypt_text(orig_file)
    
    except:
        print("The file: " + str(self.file) + " does not exist")
        sys.exit(1)
    
    return enc_text


def save_encrypted_file(self, out_name):
    with open(self.file + ".aes", 'wb') as f:
        f.write(self.encrypt_file())

def alphanumric_pass(self, key):
    num = str(key)
    return hashlib.sha256(num.encode('utf8')).digest()
```

My code to decrypt:

```
def decrypt_text(self, text, key):
    iv = text[:AES.block_size]
    password = self.alphanumric_pass(key)
    cipher = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    decrypted_text = unpad(cipher.decrypt(text[AES.block_size:]), AES.block_size)
    
    return decrypted_text
    
def decipher_file(self):
    try:
        with open(self.file, 'rb') as f:
            encrypted_file = f.read()
    except:
        print("There was an error while reading " + str(self.file))
       
    
    secret = self.get_secret() 
    num = str(secret)
    key = hashlib.sha256(num.encode('utf-8')).digest()
    decrypted_text = self.decrypt_text(encrypted_file, key)        
    return decrypted_text

def get_secret(self):
    return LagrangeInterpolation.reconstruct_secret(self.shares, 0)
    

def save_decrypted_file(self, new_name):
    with open(new_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(self.decipher_file())
```

But when I'm trying to decrypt a file I get this error:

```
    File "/home/david/Documentos/Modelado_Y_Programacion/Shamir-Secret-Share-Scheme/s4/Decrypter.py", line 38, in decrypt_text
decrypted_text = unpad(cipher.decrypt(text[AES.block_size:]), AES.block_size)
    File "/home/david/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_cbc.py", line 246, in decrypt
raise ValueError("Data must be padded to %d byte boundary in CBC mode" % self.block_size)
    ValueError: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode
```

Can someone help fix this error? I have been hours searching how to fix it, but can't find anything

Comment: AES uses a block size of 128-bits (16 bytes), your cipher text needs to be a multiple of 16 bytes.

Comment: `save_encrypted_file()` ignores the `out_name` parameter and saves the encrypted data to a file with the name of the original file plus appended _.aes_. `save_decrypted_file()` however does not read this file but the original file. This would explain the error, since the plaintext is not padded. Therefore, in `decipher_file()` `self.file` must be replaced by `self.file + ".aes"`. Unclear is however the key derivation for decryption (`LagrangeInterpolation` etc.).